# "docker run -d-p " return a sha256 code,but "docker ps": nothing,and docker logs :noting

Tags: docker

I run in my terminal:

```
docker run -d -p 8082:80 --name runoob-nginx-test-web -v ~/nginx/www:/usr/share/nginx/html -v ~/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf -v ~/nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx matt18/nginx:v1
```

and get a sha256 code:

```
072841edf0324c13939e0e95b2119f386414facd124a32de031161f21f498265
```

but

```
docker ps :  get nothing
```

```
docker ps -a  : contrainer ID: 072841edf032, STATUS: Exited (0) About a minute ago
```

```
docker logs  072841edf032 : get nothing
```

what is the problem?

Comment: The process your container ran exited without any output. Maybe add the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: before i get matt18/nginx:v1, i made some images for test, and at that time I made a Dockerfile, maybe it  affected the result, I would try to remove the Dockerfile, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

would you please check this directory `~/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` if it is empty that means nginx service cannot find its config file and exit.

Comment: yes,i checked,but its not empty,and the config file is the same as remote nginx image (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf)

Comment: what about port 8082, if you are on ubuntu machine check it like this ` sudo netstat -tpln | grep 8082` . just make sure it is not being use by some other service.

Comment: not been uesd，very strange; finally i solve the question  :  there is  a  surplus Dockerfile

Comment: great, glad to hear that.